This movie was about the Black Freedom Riders but I can't remember it
As mentioned in the title, I can't remember the name of a certain movie, it was about the early 20th century American Negro Freedom Riders, the following I remember:

The movie was set in the USA for in the early 20th century, despite it being in colour.
The protagonist is a young woman who feels sorry for the Negroes.
The woman mentioned above gets a job in the newspaper office
At some dinner with her friends (one being a racist towards the black negroes), one of the black people (as a slave) is delivering then dinner or drinks, she then disappears around the corner and listens to the white girl's conversation which is a whisper
The black woman hears some very racist stuff and goes back into the kitchen where there is another black negroe cooking stuff and they have a laugh between them.
There is one scene I remember where there was a big storm, A black woman( a slave) needed to go to the toilet (their toilets were always outside), and there was rain pouring down and lots of lightning and thunder
During this scene the white racist woman  says:


It's just a little bit of rain, take an umbrella out with you.

While she is saying this, the pool is lapping up and the mentioned umbrella is flying around outside.

So when they settle, and the black woman is desperately needing to go to the toilet, the black woman says:


I will go get you some tea and cookies

So when the black woman disappears, the white woman gets a bit suspicious, then goes quietly to the indoor bathroom and is quiet about it, she quietly closes the door. Meanwhile, the white woman goes and asks:


Are you in there?

The black woman says: 


Yes ma'am I am

As she says this, she flushes the toilet and the white woman is now screaming unintelligible stuff and the black woman throws the toilet lid down.
The black woman is fired and thrown out into the weather.
The protagonist during the course of the movie is writing a book for the black people so then people can get a better insight into their lives, and because of this book, this causes the protagonist's boyfriend to break up with her.
Another scene I remember is the black woman who was fired returns to the same house with a pie she made.
Later in that part, the white woman says:


This is really good, what did you put in it?

I can't remember what exactly happens from that point but I remember the black woman saying:


Eat ma' s**t

That is all I remember but the white woman wrote a book for the blacks people and changed their lives.

Please help me with this, I want to watch it again and I can't remember the title. Thanks guys I greatly appreciate it.

Roughly when did this movie come out? Otherwise, when did you watch it and what would you estimate the release date is (even if you can narrow down the decade)?

When I watched it is not close to the release date, I watched it sometimes two years ago. But it was in colour.

That sounds like The Help (2011) ?

An aspiring author during the civil rights movement of the 1960s
  decides to write a book detailing the African American maids' point of
  view on the white families for which they work, and the hardships they
  go through on a daily basis.

Skeeter's (the young woman) newspaper interview:



The bathroom/storm scene:



The pie scene:



